# adding a image/logo to attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, database, extensions

I am trying to use this extension as it adds a image to a attribute which i can display on the product page versus just attribute text

Extension Link
https://github.com/aligent/magento-attribute-option-image

however when i try to add a image via admin i get this error

I am presuming that it didnt install the sql stuff the code for the sql files in the extension is this

mysql4-install-1.0.0.php

$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */

$tableOption = $this->getTable('eav_attribute_option');
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("
ALTER TABLE `{$tableOption}`
    ADD `image` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL;
");

$installer->endSetup();

mysql4-upgrade-1.0.0-1.0.1.php

$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */

$tableOption = $this->getTable('eav_attribute_option');
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("
ALTER TABLE `{$tableOption}`
    ADD `thumb` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL;
");

$installer->endSetup();

so how can i manually run these so they install or how can I add the required sql stuff via phpmyadmin or something?

Comment: figured out the sql stuff :)

Comment: now how can i display this image on the front end?